# por que no se muestran las entradas de wordpress (loop) en el page.php

Tags: wordpress

mi thema usa una pagina como index ya que quiero incluir texto de forma dinámica, el inconveniente que tengo es que al cargar otra sección con los últimos post no los muestra, este es mi page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
       
    <section class="section no-pad-bot" id="article">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
            <?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
                <h1 class="center light-blue-text text-darken-3 h1-banner">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1>
                
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
               
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </section>       
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH. '/articulos.php'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

y este es articulos.php

```
<section id="articulos">
            <div class="row">
            
            <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col s12 m4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                            the_post_thumbnail('imagen_articulo_index',array('class' => 'activator'));
                        }else{echo'<img class="activator" src="http://ximg.es/600x400/000/fff">';}
                                
                        ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Seguir leyendo</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
                        
            </div>
        </section>
```

ya verifique el código y esta bien, lo que creo que puede estar generando el error es quizás porque hallan 2 loop en la misma pagina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer loop es correcto, el problema esta en el segundo loop, estas llamando al mismo, por ende causa error, lo que tiene que hacer es pasar un parámetro del post type que quieres llamar usando `query_posts()`, por ejemplo:

```
<section id="articulos">
    <div class="row">

    <?php 
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // El numero de post a mostrar, (-1 para infinito)
        'post_type'=>'post',  // El post type a llamar, en esta caso las entradas del blog
        'post_status'=>'publish', // El estado del post
        'paged' => $paged, ); 
    query_posts($args); ?>
    
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                    the_post_thumbnail('imagen_articulo_index',array('class' => 'activator'));
                }else{echo'<img class="activator" src="http://ximg.es/600x400/000/fff">';}
                        
                ?>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Seguir leyendo</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>   
                
    </div>
</section>
```

El primer loop hace una llamada de la pagina index.php y el segundo se conecta a los post del blog, si no das un argumento simplemente repetirá el mismo loop causando un error.